# Laravel: Inserting User records into the database takes a long time, but my DB is fast

Tags: laravel, heroku

I've created a test view in my Laravel app, running on Heroku, that inserts 100 users into the database by calling `User::create()` in a loop. My `users` table is pretty much stock. This takes 5-10 seconds on any database I try*. And if I have 1000 (test) users try to create accounts at once, they start timing out very quickly, after 100 or so have been inserted.

10-20 insertions per second is extremely slow for any modern Postgres or MySQL database; I've seen ~800/sec with local scripts that insert and commit each time. I think either Laravel does something slow in its PHP code when creating records, or Laravel's database interface does something to slow down the DB transactions. Has anyone experienced and solved this problem?

**Edit**: Here is my test code:

```
public static function createFake() {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
                $psw = str_random(30);
                $email = sprintf('%s@eigencoin.co', str_random(30));
                $ret = User::create([
                                'name' => $email,
                                'email' => $email,
                                'refcode' => str_random(5),
                                'password' => bcrypt($psw),
                                'referrer' => null,
                                'ip_address' => '127.0.0.1',
                                ]);
        }
        return $ret;
}
```

And my `users` table in Postgres, which is close to stock, just a few new basic columns:

```
                                         Table "public.users"
     Column     |              Type              |                     Modifiers
----------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                        | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 name           | character varying(255)         | not null
 refcode        | character varying(255)         | not null
 email          | character varying(255)         | not null
 password       | character varying(255)         | not null
 remember_token | character varying(100)         |
 created_at     | timestamp(0) without time zone |
 updated_at     | timestamp(0) without time zone |
 referrer       | character varying(255)         |
 ip_address     | character varying(45)          |
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "users_email_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
    "users_refcode_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (refcode)
    "users_referrer_index" btree (referrer)
```

**Edit 2**: I think it's the latency between the Heroku server and my database. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE insert into users(name, refcode, email, password) values ('foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4');` with `\timing on` says the planning time is 0.46ms and the execution time is 0.645ms, but the total end-to-end query time is 84ms, so ~11 queries per second. My test where I insert 100 users in one request will run them serially, but with 1000 test users connecting at once, it should be running these in parallel. So I am looking at what thread pool settings I can configure.

* Heroku free Postgres tier, Heroku standard:0 Postgres tier (expensive), Heroku ClearDB MySQL free tier, my own fast Postgres database over an SSH tunnel

Comment: It's an interesting benchmark. Can you share your test code and the database structure? So I can try it and have exactly same parameters.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra Gladly; I've edited the question.

Comment: Yeah, latency should be the issue then. Because creating user inside loops will send to database via network separately, you may try bulk insert instead. Or may be queue job.

Comment: Ok, so that benchmark doesn't simulate real usage. I'll go back to testing with 1000 test clients, which also indicates that it's very slow, but I'm trying adjusting some Heroku settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out myself, based on some information a teammate later gave me about the quick query time that put me on the right track.

The "problem" is my Heroku server apparently has a large latency time to its database, >80ms as I said in edit 2. I was expecting them to colocate them automatically, but I guess not? The classic solution is to have a lot of webserver threads, each with its own DB connection, so that the overall task of having X users sign up at once can be parallelized.

The real problem: Turns out, each PHP worker gets 128MiB RAM by default. Heroku explains this is a conservative setting; my app does fine with 16MiB or even 8. And TBH I also forgot to check and didn't notice my server only had 1GiB. So that's only 8 database connections. So in the end, the unexpected conditions of the Heroku servers were causing poor performance under the default settings you get from following tutorials, but all it takes is some tweaks to your settings...

**Solution:** Add `memory_limit = 16M` (or whatever amount works) to `.user.ini` in your public dir (`/public` in Laravel) to have less RAM per worker => more workers per server, [explained here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-concurrency#tuning-concurrency-using-memory_limit). Also have to ensure that the database will allow that many connections. Or if you can't, use pgbouncer to work around the problem.

Using Loader.io to test 1000 clients hitting a page that creates just 1 user each time, I saw much better performance after increasing the number of web threads this way.

Comment: You can use [mysqlslap](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlslap.html) for mysql testing and diagnostics. Check [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-measure-mysql-query-performance-with-mysqlslap) for basic example use case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an array of fake users and then just insert once on the database instead of multiple times? Something like this should work (I have not tested this code!)

```
public static function fakeUsers() {
    $users = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $psw = str_random(30);
        $email = sprintf('%s@eigencoin.co', str_random(30));

        array_push($users,[
            'name' => $email,
            'email' => $email,
            'refcode' => str_random(5),
            'password' => bcrypt($psw),
            'referrer' => null,
            'ip_address' => '127.0.0.1',
        ]);
    }
    return $users;
}

public static function createFake() {
    return User::insert(self::fakeUsers());
}
```

Comment: It'll help, but the only reason I was inserting one at a time was to test my database performance. The actual use case of the site is that users will be signing up individually, so each request will create one record, and I'll have many requests.

Comment: Cool. Got it :)